# Replace a value in the dataframe with another column from a different table

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
player_ref first_name 
1          a
2          b
3          c
```

and another dataset with two columns

```
uid shortname

1          d
2          e
3          f
```

I would like to replace the values where `player_ref == uid`. Instead of havind the `first_name`, I want the shortname. It would look like this:

```
player_ref first_name 
1          d
2          e
3          f
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: There're so many ways to do this. I cant find a dupe right now, but I'd suggest a minute or two in google ;p

Comment: Key word for search , replace , map , merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try (in case that player_ref == uid):

```
df_player.first_name = df_uid.shortname
```

or if player_ref != uid (with example):

```
df_player = pd.DataFrame({'player_ref': [1, 2 ,3, 4], 'first_name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

df_uid = pd.DataFrame({'uid': [4, 2, 1, 3], 'shortname': ['e','f','g', 'h']})

df_player.first_name = [df_uid[df_uid.uid == p].shortname.values[0] for p in df_player.player_ref]

df_player
```

[image]

or using map:

```
df_player.first_name = df_player.player_ref.map(dict(e for e in zip(df_uid.uid, df_uid.shortname)))
```

Comment: Not what OP wants

Comment: then the OP has to choose a better example, it just happens that uid and player_ref are identical

Comment: @rafaelc what about now?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `player_ref` is the DataFrame index, you could use a [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), a [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and a [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) on you DataFrames:

```py
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['a','b','c','d']
}, index=[1,2,3,4])

d2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'shortname': ['e','f','g','h']
}, index=[4,2,1,3])

result = d1.join(d2, how='inner').drop('first_name', axis=1).rename({'shortname': 'first_name'}, axis=1)
```

Comment: will not work if uid != player_ref, so is not what OP wants

Comment: Maybe an inner join (`d = d1.join(d2, how='inner').drop('first_name', axis=1).rename({'shortname': 'first_name'}, axis=1)`) would do the trick then?

Comment: nup, you can try with my example or any other example :)

Comment: Before that I do this: `tmp = player_df['player_ref'].isin(idsd_df['uid'])`
So the values present in player_ref are in the uid, I just want to replace the first name of the player_ref 1 with the shortname of the player with uid 1.

Comment: I've updated my answer and it seems to do the job. What is wrong with it? :)